# Prevent self-callbacks when changing observed collection

Tags: c#, .net

Let's suppose I have an observable collection and two clients that want to:

- change it,
- observe it and react on state change.

Now, if Client1 changes collection state (for example: adds new item), the collection will fire 'CollectionChanged' event. Since both clients are registered for this event notifications, Client1's handling method will be executed.

In order to avoid self-callback on Client1, I unsubscribe from an event, do my action and subscribe again. This is painful - I must remember about suspending Client1's subscription every time Client1 touches the collection and it just seems like a bad smell. Is there a better way (design pattern, external library) that would help me in callbacks management?

Although in my example I mentioned ObservableCollection and CollectionChanged event, I believe my question is more generic and comes down to: "how to exclude an entity that caused event trigger from event callback".

Thanks in advance!

---

Problem keeps reoccuring in my solution, bumping the question in a hope someone might help out.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into your problem some times ago I didn't find a proper solution except for this one.

The idea is that when you change the collection you also pass an instance of the object changing it.

Then when the Collection fires the event, it also passes the reference.

So all observers may know which instance did the change, and check for equality.

Here is a basic example of this implementation:

```
class Program
{
    private static MyCollection Collection;
    private static MyCollectionModifier Modif1;
    private static MyCollectionModifier Modif2;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Collection = new MyCollection();
        Modif1 = new MyCollectionModifier("Modifier 1", Collection);
        Modif2 = new MyCollectionModifier("Modifier 2", Collection);

        Modif1.AddItem("Test1");
        Modif2.AddItem("Test2");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class MyCollectionItemAddedEventArgs:EventArgs
{
    public Object ChangeSource { get; set;}
    public int newIndex {get;set;}
}

public delegate void MyCollectionItemAddedEventHandler(object sender, MyCollectionItemAddedEventArgs e);

public class MyCollection
{
    private List<String> _myList;

    public  String this[int Index]
    {
        get { return _myList[Index]; }
    }

    public event MyCollectionItemAddedEventHandler ItemAdded;

   public  MyCollection()
    {
        _myList = new List<string>();
    }

    protected virtual void OnMyCollectionItemAdded(MyCollectionItemAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ItemAdded != null)
            ItemAdded(this, e);
    }

    public void AddItem(String Item, object ChangeSource = null)
    {
        _myList.Add(Item);
        var e = new MyCollectionItemAddedEventArgs();
        e.ChangeSource = ChangeSource;
        e.newIndex = _myList.Count;
        OnMyCollectionItemAdded(e);
    }
}

public class MyCollectionModifier
{
    private MyCollection _collection;
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public MyCollectionModifier(string Name, MyCollection Collection)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        _collection = Collection;
        _collection.ItemAdded += Collection_ItemAdded;
    }

    public void AddItem(string Item)
    {
        _collection.AddItem(Item, this);
    }

    void Collection_ItemAdded(object sender, MyCollectionItemAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e != null)
        {
            if (this.Equals(e.ChangeSource))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} : I changed the collection", Name);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} : Somebody else changed the collection", Name);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I +1'ed you too early :P. As far as I checked, ObservedCollection passes reference to itself as a 'sender' argument, so it cannot be used to decide who caused event raise. Still, I believe the concept may be adopted in some way in case of custom events.

Comment: But since I am a lazy I hope someone encountered this issue before and implemented dedicated library for more advanced event handling.

Comment: Got it, that's more or less what I have expected from your first post. Still, I hope that there is a way to do it without adding information about source of change to event data.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this problem before as well.
Best solution I could come up with is to create extension methods that take the handler of the caller and then automate the unsubscribe/subscribe around the called method, that way you don't have to remember to do it each time and it does not end up cluttering your code either

```
 public static void Add<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> self, T itemToAdd, NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler handler)
    {
        self.CollectionChanged -= handler;
        self.Add(itemToAdd);
        self.CollectionChanged += handler;
    }
```

It does take some effort to create the extensions initially but at least you won't forget to resubscribe. Only real extra code is then around invoking the method

```
public class ObserverClass
{
    public ObserverClass()
    {
        ObservableIntegers.CollectionChanged += ObservableIntegersOnCollectionChanged;
        //Add item to collection while preventing self-handling the callback
        ObservableIntegers.Add(1, ObservableIntegersOnCollectionChanged);
    }

    private void ObservableIntegersOnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs notifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)
    {
        // Handle collection change
    }

    public ObservableCollection<int> ObservableIntegers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this approach. I am still not fully convinced as it requires remembering about implementing those wraps for every method that changes the collection. Still I am glad you shared your suggestion.